# math accent before starred macro, with unicode-math or without amsmath

Tags: macros, accents, starred-version

I have a macro `\makebold` which takes a star and a shortcut `\aaa`.  I'm trying to use `\aaa` after `\bar` to produce a barred, bold letter.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{xparse, unicode-math}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \makebold { s m }{%
    \mathbf{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\aaa}{\makebold*{b}}

\begin{document}Test $\bar\aaa$.\end{document}
```

produces the following:

```
! Missing { inserted.
<to be read again>
                   \l__xparse_processor_int
l.16 Test $\bar\aaa
                   $.
```

It works if I remove the `s` option to `DeclareDocumentCommand`.  I further tried,

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % <- removing this line produces error
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareDocumentCommand \makebold { s m }{%
    \mathbf{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\aaa}{\makebold*{b}}

\begin{document}Test $\bar\aaa$.\end{document}
```

This works.  I remove the line `\usepackage{amsmath}`, it does not.  What's going on here?  How can I modify the two macros so they work with `unicode-math` or without `amsmath`?

Comment: Using `\bar x` is wrong and it should be `\bar{x}`; if you are always consistent with this usage, you'd input `\bar{\aaa}` and the problem would disappear.

Comment: @egreg, do you say this because of the precise nature of `\bar` or would `\foo x` (where `foo` is defined to take one argument) be equally wrong?  Is `\mathbf x` wrong also?

Comment: `\mathbf x` is conceptually wrong; it works, but promotes bad coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in all your cases is that you don't use braces around the argument of `\bar`.

When TeX expands tokens, without the `amsmath` package being loaded `\bar` expands to `\mathaccent "7016\relax`. After that TeX expects a single character or a subformula in braces. In you case the braces are missing, so `\aaa` is expanded and the first token `\l__xparse_processor_int` of that expansion (coming from `\makebold`) causes problems.

However, if you load the `amsmath` package, `\bar` is redefined such that more care is taken when the token after it is expanded.

So the most simple solution is to just use braces: `\bar{\aaa}`. If you really don't want that, for whaterver reason, you can also redefine `\bar` to automatically add braces around its argument (and keep your fingers crossed that this doesn't break at other places/with other packages):

```
\let\oldbar\bar
\renewcommand\bar[1]{\oldbar{#1}}
```

Comment: You also need to allow for the Unicode issue: `\mathbf` is the wrong command with `unicode-math` here, `\symbf` is needed.

Comment: Just for further understanding of expansion, is there any feature that can instead wrap `\aaa` to cause `\bar\aaa` to be expanded as `\mathaccent "7016\relax{\makebold a}`, with the braces?

Comment: @Mass If you mean to expand without the star, you have to redefine `\aaa` to `\makebold a`. Otherwise this is what already happens with the last to lines

Comment: @JosephWright Ah, indeed, I hadn't thought to sanity-check whether `\bar{\mathbf{a}}` worked with `unicode-math` (it does not).